# How can I have google maps API refind the longitude and latitude when place_changed is not activated?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my web app, I give the user the ability to go back and edit the information that they entered.  However, for some reason when they resubmit, the locations latitude/longitude does not recalculate.  This happens when they don't change the job location.  Is there a way to make google maps find that job location without any user interference?

My code is below:

```
var jobLocationChanged = false;
var jobLocationpickChanged  = false;
function initialize() {
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.348565,-122.263069),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.496039,-122.062912));

  var options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds,
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
  };

  var input = document.getElementById('jobLocation');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // Inform the user that a place was not found and return.
        return;
      }
      $('#jobLocation-lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
      $('#jobLocation-lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      //$('#jobLocation-pos-label').text('Lat  : '+place.geometry.location.lat()+', Lng  : '+place.geometry.location.lng());
      jobLocationChanged = false;
  });

    var input2 = document.getElementById('jobLocationpick');
    var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // Inform the user that a place was not found and return.
        return;
      }
      $('#jobLocationpick-lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
      $('#jobLocationpick-lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      //$('#jobLocationpick-pos-label').text('Lat  : '+place.geometry.location.lat()+', Lng  : '+place.geometry.location.lng());
      jobLocationpickChanged = false;
    });



}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I would really appreciate any help!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may request the predictions for the given string via the [**Autocomplete-Service**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service)